# Como fazer um select de um período Noturno (18hrs as 6hrs)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Descrição:
Contar quantas vezes a ação ocorreu no período noturno considerando a hora de 18:00 até 06:00 da manhã.

Existe uma maneira melhor para efetuar um select desse tipo sem ter que usar o *or*
para comparar os períodos?

```
select count(*) as contador,log_desc,'Noite' from log
where extract(hour from log_data_hora)>=0 and extract(hour fromlog_data_hora)<6  
or  extract(hour from log_data_hora)>18 and extract(hour from log_data_hora)<=23  
group by log_desc,cor_cod
```

Estou utilizando o PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o operador BETWEEN em conjunto com NOT para isso:

```
select count(*) as contador,log_desc,'Noite' from log
where extract(hour from log_data_hora) NOT BETWEEN 6 AND 17
group by log_desc,cor_cod
```

Comment: Utilizando esse BETWEEN pegaria todo o período(*manha*,*tarde*) e quero somente o período noturno, correspondendo de 18 horas até 6 da manhã.

Comment: @AndrewAlex Por isso o uso de negação (NOT). A expressão acima se lê: 'Retorne todos os registros onde a hora NÃO se encontre entre 6 e 17', o que cobriria até 17:59.

Comment: Correto agora funcionou. Simples e funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Meu amigo, eu não sei qual é o db que esta usando, mas no padrao SQL Ansi a query ficaria assim.

```
select count(*) as contador,log_desc,'Noite' from log
where log_data_hora >= '2015-03-02 18:00:00.000' and log_data_hora <= '2015-03-03     06:00:00.000'
group by log_desc,cor_cod
```

Comment: No caso isso não funcionaria, pois não quero uma data especifica *'2015-03-02'*, quero agrupar por período independente do dia, usando a resposta do @OnoSendai deu certo.